# Is the trivial homomorphic image of a field a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, ring-homomorphism

Let $F$ be a field and $\phi$ be a trivial homomorphism such that $\phi(x) = 0$ for every $x\in F$.  The homomorphic image of $F$ in such case is therefore a ring, not a field.

Is this correct?

(I ask for there is a question, F6 of Chapter 18, in Pinter's Abstract Algebra to prove that any homomorphic image of a field is a field, which doesn't seem to hold in all cases.)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that's correct; the zero ring isn't a field. (This is an example of the ["too simple to be simple"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple) phenomenon).

The exercise is close though, the homomorphic image of a field is either 0 or another field.

Comment: Actually, if http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf is the book OP is using, it actually defines fields to include the zero ring.  Of course this is not the standard definition, though.

Comment: Homomorphisms are required to preserve structure. If you require $1 \neq 0 $ in a field (as is standard), then $\{0\}$ cannot be the image of a field homomorphism.

Comment: p.172:

"If $A$ is a commutative ring with unity in which every nonzero element is invertible, $A$ is called a field."

By this definition, the zero ring cannot be a field as it has no unity element.

Comment: Rob Arthan, where the question is asked, the book has not defined nor mentioned field homomorphism; only ring homomorphism.

Comment: Given your quotation from Pinter's book, Pinter is adopting the unusual convention that the zero ring is a field: in the zero ring $\{0\}$, $0$ acts as a unit element ($1$) for multiplication. It is usual to require $1 \neq 0$, but not all authors do.

Comment: Thanks, Rob Arthan.  Mystery solved.